# Jersey Client API - authentication

Tags: authentication, client, jersey

I'm using the Jersey client API to submit SOAP requests to a JAX-WS webservice. By default Jersey is somehow using my Windows Nt credentials for authentication when challenged. Can anyone explain where Jersey does this in the code? And can it be overriden?

I have tried using HTTPBasicAuthFilter and adding as a filter on the Client. I have also tried adding my credentials to the WebResoruce queryParams field however neither are being picked up.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

At first I got this working as documented in the Jersey User guide

```
Authenticator.setDefault (authinstance);
```

However I did not like this as it relied on setting a global authenticator.  After some research I discovered that Jersey has a `HTTPBasicAuthFilter` which is even easier to use.

```
Client c = Client.create();
c.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(user, password));
```

See:
[https://jersey.github.io/nonav/apidocs/1.10/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/filter/HTTPBasicAuthFilter.html](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.10/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/filter/HTTPBasicAuthFilter.html)
[https://jersey.github.io/nonav/apidocs/1.10/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/filter/Filterable.html#addFilter(com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.ClientFilter)](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.10/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/filter/Filterable.html#addFilter%28com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.ClientFilter%29)

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. I added this to our client and used Spring Security on the server piece. Worked very elegantly to add security to the application.

Comment: See answer below for Jersey 2.x

Comment: I did this: `HTTPBasicAuthFilter feature = new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(restUsername,restPassword); client.addFilter(feature);` but for some unknown reason i keep getting feature as `null`. Why would it happen,any idea?

Answer (score 38):

Jersey 2.x:

```java
HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basicBuilder()
    .nonPreemptive()
    .credentials("user", "password")
    .build();

ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
clientConfig.register(feature) ;

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
```

Reference: [5.9.1. Http Authentication Support](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/client.html#d0e5464)

Comment: or: Response response = client.target("http://localhost:8080/rest/homer/contact").request()
    .property(HTTP_AUTHENTICATION_BASIC_USERNAME, "homer")
    .property(HTTP_AUTHENTICATION_BASIC_PASSWORD, "p1swd745").get();

Comment: I did the same!! But still no authentication is working!.

Comment: This does not work for me and I still get 403 responses. I am not using HTTPS as I don't have a certificate and am trying to test this locally. Does this basic auth HAVE TO use HTTPS? Is there a way to force it to work over plain HTTP? I don't care that it's not SSL.

Answer (score 11):

There's a small section in the Jersey User guide about [Client authentication](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e784). I'd recommend you follow its advice and try using [Apache HTTP Client](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.8/contribs/jersey-apache-client/com/sun/jersey/client/apache/package-summary.html) instead of HttpURLConnection, as it has much better support for just about anything you'd want to do.

Answer (score 6):

Adding this answer as I keep finding answers for older versions of Jersey that are no longer relevant in 2.x.

For Jersey 2 there are several ways. 
Take a look at:

[JavaDoc for org.glassfish.jersey.client.authentication.HttpAuthenticationFeature](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/client/authentication/HttpAuthenticationFeature.html)

Here is the one that is working for me (simplest basic auth IMHO).

```
    ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();

    HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic("username", "password");

    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
    client.register(feature);

    WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://api.asite.com/api").path("v1/reports/list");
    Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder =  webTarget.request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE);

    Response response = invocationBuilder.get();

    System.out.println( response.getStatus() );
    System.out.println( response.readEntity(String.class) );
```

Comment: This was useful for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing a Dropwizard application (maybe it suits any REST service), you can use this as an example:
https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/v0.8.1/dropwizard-auth/src/test/java/io/dropwizard/auth/basic/BasicAuthProviderTest.java

Answer (score 0):

Please find following working code without SSL

I am using put request , if need post/get just change it.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>JerseyJSONExample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Java Class

```
package com.rest.jersey.jerseyclient;

import com.rest.jersey.dto.Employee;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPBasicAuthFilter;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.LoggingFilter;
import com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONConfiguration;

public class JerseyClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            String username = "username";
            String password = "p@ssword";


            //{"userId":"12345","name ":"Viquar","surname":"Khan","email":"Vaquar.khan@gmail.com"}





            Employee employee = new Employee("Viquar", "Khan", "Vaquar.khan@gmail.com");


            ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();

            clientConfig.getFeatures().put( JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);

            Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);
            //


                final HTTPBasicAuthFilter authFilter = new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(username, password);
                client.addFilter(authFilter);
                client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter());

            //
            WebResource webResource = client
                    .resource("http://localhost:7001/VaquarKhanWeb/employee/api/v1/informations");

              ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
                .type("application/json").put(ClientResponse.class, employee);


            if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + response.getStatus());
            }

            String output = response.getEntity(String.class);

            System.out.println("Server response .... \n");
            System.out.println(output);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}
```

POJO

```
package com.rest.jersey.dto;

public class Employee {

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String email;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [name=" + name + ", surname=" + surname + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }
    public Employee(String name, String surname, String email) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes for jersey 2.x you can do this to authenticate each request with basic auth (preemptive mode):

```
 client.register(HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic(userName, password));
 // rest invocation code ..
```