# JerseyClient using DefaultHttpClient

Tags: client, httpclient, jersey

I need to access a JAX-WS webservice protected by SSL using Jersey Client. I have successfully got this working with limited configuration and just letting the Client use the default HTTPURLConnection API.

This approach wont work however for my overall solution because it does not allow me the flexibility to change the credentials used when making a request to the WS. I'm trying to use DefaultHTTPClient instead and then passing it to the Client object on intialization.

```
NTCredentials credentials = new NTCredentials("username", "password",
    computerName, domainName);
DefaultHttpClient httpClienttemp = new DefaultHttpClient();
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = wrapClient(httpClienttemp);
httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials );
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
```

The wrapClient method creates an X509TrustManager and overrides the necessary methods so that all certificates are accepted. It also creates a SchemeRegistry entry for https access on port 443. This configuration results in a Connection refused exception.

The strange thing is, if i add an additional entry in the SchemeRegistry for http and give it a port of 443 then the request does get sent however a Connection Reset exception then gets thrown.

The Url i use to create the WebResource object is https however the SOAPAction i declare in the header uses http. Any ideas where im going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of the default HTTP Client (com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client) documented in the Jersey docs. You will have to use Apache HTTP Client to achieve this functionality.

Looks like someone already recommended doing this in the answer to your previous question: [Jersey Client API - authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774506/jersey-client-api-authentication).

**EDIT:** Corrected reference to the default Jersey HTTP Client to avoid confusion.

Comment: the Defaulthttpclient and the Apachehttpclient appear to be the same?? In my previous email i was using the default option that Jersey Clients chooses which is the HttpURLConnection API

Comment: Jersey Apache HTTP Client in Jersey using Apache HttpClient library while the DefaultHttpClient is using HttpURLConnection.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! I meant default Jersey HTTP Client and edited my answer to reflect this. What DefaultHttpClient are you referring to? I don't see it in the jersey-bundle 1.8 API documentation: http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/index.html