# Rest - Jersey.Client pass @SecurityContext to Server

Tags: rest, tomcat, jersey, restful-authentication

I want to pass a security context to my rest service.

On server side I try to get this with:

```
 public Response postObject(@Context SecurityContext security, JAXBElement<Object> object) {
    System.out.println("Security Context: " + security.getUserPrincipal());
 .....
```

But actually the Syso is null.

On Client side im just doing:

```
    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    Client client = Client.create(config);
    client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("user", "password"));
```

So, do I have to change in addition something in my web.xml to get it working?

I hoped its working without setting up static users in the tomcat user xml. So I can compare the user/password from security context with my "persistent" user/password hashmap located server sided. But when it is not working without tomcat user xml, how can it be done to add dynamically user to that user xml? When I ve static users I cant register a new user. I dont want to use this attempt: http://objecthunter.congrace.de/tinybo/blog/articles/89 cuz I want just to work with a semi persistence like a HashMap of user/password.

Besides another question: Why does everybody refer to Apache HttpClient when it is about security in Jersey, when it is working like I wrote as well?

My attempt refers to this post:

[Jersey Client API - authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774506/jersey-client-api-authentication)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up your application on the server so that it requires Basic authentication. I.e. include something like the following in the web.xml in your application war file - otherwise Tomcat does not perform the authentication and does not populate the security context.

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Authentication Constraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>all</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description>authentication required</description>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>realm_name</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

Comment: Yeah, thats the web.xml part. I read alot about my issue. It seems that I can't work with a semi persistent map of users. On the one hand I can just work with static users declared in the tomcat-user.xml and on the other hand I could do it with dynamic users from my db.