# Securing RESTful webservices (Jersey on Tomcat)

Tags: java, security, jersey, ws-security

I have implemented a number of web services using `Jersey`. What I need to do now is to secure them. This means I need to encrypt the data transferred and authenticate users. The server I'm using is `Tomcat`

Is there any articles and tutorials for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For encryption you can use https in tomcat.  [Here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) is the guide on how to do it.
For authentication you can use have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774506/jersey-client-api-authentication).

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Can you give me a better tutorial on Authenticating using Jersey?

Comment: @M-T-A [Here](http://javaevangelist.blogspot.in/2012/07/jax-rs-tip-of-day-basic-client_27.html) is one blog with and example.

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you dont have specifics, You should use Token Based Authentication.

The authentication happens on another service, and not with the rest service, once authenticated, the token can be used and given to the client to access REST services.