# Jersey-client basic authentication

Tags: java, http, basic-authentication, jersey-client

I'm trying to send a REST-request over HTTPS that includes basic authentication in the HTTP header, the problem seem to be that the authentication does not get inserted into the header.

```
    HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature
            .basicBuilder().build();

    Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(getSSLContext())
            .hostnameVerifier(getHostNameVerifier()).build();
    client.register(feature);
    client.register(new LoggingFilter());
    try
    {
        String entity = client
                .target(url)
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .property(
                        HttpAuthenticationFeature.HTTP_AUTHENTICATION_BASIC_USERNAME,
                        "username")
                .property(
                        HttpAuthenticationFeature.HTTP_AUTHENTICATION_BASIC_PASSWORD,
                        "password").get(String.class);

        System.out.println(entity);
    } catch (WebApplicationException e)
    {
        ByteArrayInputStream in = (ByteArrayInputStream) e.getResponse()
                .getEntity();
        int n = in.available();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[n];
        in.read(bytes, 0, n);
        String entity = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println(entity);
    }
```

What the log says:

```
Jun 16, 2015 2:06:53 PM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 1 * Sending client request on thread JavaFX Application Thread
1 > GET https://url
1 > Accept: application/xml

Jun 16, 2015 2:06:53 PM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 2 * Client response received on thread JavaFX Application Thread
2 < 403
2 < Connection: Keep-Alive
2 < Content-Length: 240
2 < Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
2 < Date: Tue, 16 Jun 2015 12:06:53 GMT
2 < Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
```

And the result code is just 403 Forbidden.

If I remove the line `client.register(feature);` the line `2 < WWW-authenticate: basic realm="/"` gets added to the end of the log and the result code is 401 Authorization Requried instead of 403.

The REST-request works fine when using HTTP Requester in FireFox.

I guess I'm just missing something somewhere?

Comment: Are your sure that the credentials ("username" and "password") are valid?

Comment: Do you have the possibility to log the raw request and copy it to your post? The raw request should contain a header like `Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=`

Comment: The log is the request + response header, as you can see the request header does not contain an `Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=` line

Comment: @vonyx have you already tried [this method here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774506/jersey-client-api-authentication)?

Comment: @RomanVottner Yup and same result sadly.

Answer (score 4):

If you are required to use Pre-Jersey 2.X this is quite difficult, as is apparent. If you need to do HTTPS (SSL) Basic Authentication then it gets ridiculously easy with Jersey 2.X onwards. 
These instructions are using Jersey 2.25.1:

1. If you are using a [self-signed certificate](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate.html) you must first download the .cer/.crt/.cet file from the HTTPS page from within your browser after authenticating with valid login. [Guide](https://success.outsystems.com/Support/Enterprise_Customers/Installation/Install_a_trusted_root_CA__or_self-signed_certificate), [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617210/how-to-properly-import-a-selfsigned-certificate-into-java-keystore-that-is-avail)
2. Then use different Feature (javax.ws.rs.core) implementations in Jersey 2.X to enter all this information in.

Sample code for building WebTarget and Client with SSLContext:

```
HttpAuthenticationFeature auth = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic("admin", password);
SslConfigurator config = SslConfigurator.newInstance()
        .keyStoreFile("C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\jre\lib\security\cacerts")
        .keyPassword("changeit");
SSLContext sslContext = config.createSSLContext();
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
        .sslContext(sslContext)
        .register(SseFeature.class)
        .register(auth)
        .build();
WebTarget target = client.target(sourcePath);
```