# how to get Json Data from rest api

Tags: java, rest

I want to get JSON data from a REST API.

I wrote a simple Java class as Jersey client to connect to the web service but when I execute the class, he displays HTML, not JSON.
knowing that the API is authentication with login and password and I don't know how I process.
Here is the source code for the class I tried to write.

```
{
    public class RestClient {

    public static void main(String ar[]) throws Exception
    {

        String baseUrl="??????????????";
        String password="???????????";
        String user="?????????";       

        ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
        Client client = Client.create(config);

        WebResource service = client.resource(baseUrl);
        service.path("j_spring_security_check");
        service.queryParam("j_username", user);
        service.queryParam("j_password", user);
        service.queryParam("ajax", "true");
        String out = service.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);
        System.out.println(out);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would depend, at least in part, on just what rest API you are trying to talk to, which you have neglected to share.

Comment: thank you  @Scott Hunter , it is an API company owner, I'm trying to build a customer jersey
API implements a basic authentication

Comment: I did not understand is that the connection parameters, I should send in the header (queryparams ()) or there is another solution

Answer (score 0):

As the other guys said it depends on the REST API. you're code looks o.k. but maybe try using the code below and insert query parameters into url
like so: /?parmam1=value1&param2=value2

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);
String jsonResult = webResource.accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class).getEntity(String.class);
```

Comment: Thank you @Tal Joffe ,I ask you  how I  can use basic authentication în  jersey client

Comment: in your code it looks like authentication is used via query parameters and on that case my example works.
if you something more complex try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774506/jersey-client-api-authentication